# How add to BASS Audio Library to references in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, bass, bass.dll

I have attempted to add BASS.dll to my references in my project and it keeps complaining on how it can't add it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add a reference to BASS.dll. You need to add a reference to Bass.net.dll 
You just need to make sure that both files are in your debug folder.